# Can we edit configuration profile in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, configuration, profile

I came across an app on iTunes that allows you to restrict your child accessing camera app and other apps by just installing  configuration profile sent by them over the air.You can alter the setting through their app. I searched about it and found that we can hide  apps like camera,Appstore by creating configuration profile using iPhone configuration utility. But i stuck on the question that can we edit configuration profile XML pro grammatically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can edit/create the configuration profile programatically. Configuration profile is just a plist file that contains the information/restrictions. Once you could create the plist file, you can install it into your iOS devices. Plist file contains various commands and keys associated. The detailed description is available in [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef.pdf). By creating a suitable plist file with specific payload you could accomplish your need.